# Speed of querying columns in different ways (SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

This is really fast:

```
tgt_ids = [x.id for x in DBSession.query(getattr(cls, 'id')).all()]
```

This is really slow:

```
tgt_ids = [x.id for x in DBSession.query(cls).options(load_only('id')).all()]
```

I've observed SQL between the two is similar and executed very quickly, but in the latter case Python causes high CPU load for like 30s.

Why?

(`cls` is typical user SQA class defined in declarative manner)

Comment: @Ilja Turn this into answer pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be the fact that

```
tgt_ids = [x.id for x in DBSession.query(getattr(cls, 'id')).all()]
```

produces result tuples containing `(<type of your id column>,)` (result tuples are labeled, so that's why x.id works), but

```
tgt_ids = [x.id for x in DBSession.query(cls).options(load_only('id')).all()]
```

constructs full model objects, but fills only the id attribute.